# Why doesn't message box block the thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

Consider following code snippet where a message box is displayed upon a WM_TIMER message.

```
#define IDT_TIMER1 1001

INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch(message) {

        //...

        case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {
            //...

            SetTimer(hWnd, IDT_TIMER1, 1000, (TIMERPROC)NULL);

            break;
        }
        case WM_TIMER:
        {
            int ret = MessageBox(hWnd, L"Cancel operation?", NULL, MB_YESNO);
            if(ret == IDYES) {
                EndDialog(hWnd, 0);
            } else {
                // no-op: keep going
            }

            break;
        }

        //...

        default:
            return FALSE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

I expect this code to display a message box at initial timer tick, and block the thread until user clicks a button. What **actually** happens is that a **new** message box is displayed at **each** timer tick even though user does **not** click any of the buttons.

When I inspect the call stack of the thread, I see multiple calls to `DialogProc()`, all stuck on line where `MessageBox()` is called(i.e. all waiting for user input).

Given the state of the call stack, how is it possible that `DialogProc()` keeps getting called in the **same** thread where `MessageBox()` has **not yet returned** in the last call to `DialogProc()`?

P.S. Note that I am not asking how to accomplish the desired behavior. I am only looking for insights to understand what is going on "under the hood" resulting in the actual behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MessageBox` enters nested message loop needed for rendering window, handling buttons.

Window specified as first argument in `MessageBox` call, has input disabled by `EnableWindow` but this doesn't disable all messages so you still receive WM_PAINT, WM_TIMER and others. Generally it disables user input: mouse, keyboard, but also window sizing with mouse.

This pseudo-code shows how MessageBox analog could be potentially implemented:

```
int MessageBox( HWND owner_hwnd, ... )
{
    ...
    HWND box_hwnd = CreateWindowEx( ..., owner_hwnd, ... );
    ...
    EnableWindow( owner_hwnd, FALSE );
    ...
    while ( !done )
    {
        MSG msg;
        GetMessage( &msg, ... );
        if ( IsDialogMessage( box_hwnd, &msg ) )
            continue;
        TranslateMessage( &msg );
        DispatchMessage( &msg );
    }
    ...
    EnableWindow( owner_hwnd, TRUE );
    ...
    DestroyWindow( box_hwnd );
    ...
    return button;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

`MessageBox` launches a new [Message Loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927(v=vs.85).aspx), which amongst other things, has access to and will call your `DialogProc`, by the normal Windows callback mechanisms.

If it didn't do that then events like `WM_PAINT` wouldn't get handled and your app would look like it had died (apart from the message box). Because the timer is still running, the `WM_TIMER` events are enqueued at appropriate times.